# react-hook-forms - problelm with setting default values for fields array

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-hook-form

I have a table with component rows, each row renders multiple fields with user controls. User controls are Fluent UI controls wrapped in Controller components. Using react-hook-forms I'm trying to wire them up, unfortunately I'm getting warnings about defaultValues, and I'm not sure how to resolve this.
The warnings in the console are along the lines:

*react_devtools_backend.js:2430  rows[0].DataSprzedazy is missing in the 'defaultValue' prop of either its Controller (https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller) or useForm (https://react-hook-form.com/api#useForm)*

I'm trying to set defaultValue on each Controller directly from the dataRows state. I understand that in case of field arrays name has to be specific, but I can't find a case like mine anywhere. If I understand correctly, useFieldsArray described in documentation is for uncontrolled inputs. Any ideas?

This is from my parent:

```
    const {register, handleSubmit, control, errors} = useForm();
    const [dataRows, setDataRows] = React.useState(emptyRowArr);

[...]



    return (

      <div className={styles.rozliczeniaFaktur}>
      <Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
      {isError && <MessageBar messageBarType={MessageBarType.error} isMultiline={false} >
        {errorMessage}
      </MessageBar>} 
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
      <div className={styles.dataTable}>
        <div className={styles.scrollContainer}>
        <table id='rozliczenia' className={styles.table}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
[...]
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             {dataRows && 
                dataRows.map((dataRow, i) => {
                  return <TableRowControl web={web} key={i} Context={context} RowId={i} PozFaktury={dataRow} FormType={formType}
                    onAddRowCallback={addRow} onDeleteRowCallback={delRow} ZaliczkaDictionary={zaliczkaDictionary}
                    OrganizacjaDictionary={organizacjaDictionary} VatDictionary={vatDictionary} MpkDictionary={mpkDictionary}
                    KontoDictionary={kontoDictionary} ZastepstwaDictionary={zastepstwaDictionary} 
                     control={control} errors={errors} register={register} />
                })
              }
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <DefaultButton />
      </form>
```

And this is on my TableRowControl:

```
const TableRowControl = ({RowId, Context, PozFaktury, FormType, onAddRowCallback, onDeleteRowCallback, web, 
    onErrorCallback, OrganizacjaDictionary, VatDictionary, MpkDictionary, KontoDictionary, ZastepstwaDictionary,
    ZaliczkaDictionary, control, errors, register} : ITableRowControlProps) => {   

[...]
    return(
        <tr>
            <td className={styles.cell}>
                <IconButton onClick={()=> onAddRowCallback(RowId)} iconProps={{ iconName: 'Add' }} title="Dodaj" ariaLabel="Dodaj" />
                <IconButton onClick={()=> onDeleteRowCallback(RowId)} iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }} title="Usuń" ariaLabel="Usuń" />
            </td>
            {/* Oddzial rozliczenia */}
            <td  className={styles.cell}>
                <ControlledDropdown options={OrganizacjaDictionary.map(i => {return { key: i.Title, text: i.Organizacja }})} 
                defaultValue={PozFaktury.OddzialRozliczenia} control={control} name={`rows[${RowId}].OddzialRozliczenia`}
                errors={errors}  />

            </td>
            {/* Oddzial macierzysty */}
            <td  className={styles.cell}>
                <Label>{PozFaktury.OddzialMacierzysty}</Label>
            </td>
            {/* Pracownik */}
            <td className={styles.cell}>
                <Label>{PozFaktury.Pracownik}</Label>
            </td>
            
[...]
        </tr>
        );
```

Also dataRows const is array of these kind of objects:

```
export interface IPozFaktury {
    OddzialRozliczenia: number | null;
    OddzialMacierzysty: number | null;
    Pracownik: string;
    IDFaktury: string;
    DataSprzedazy: Date | null;
    DataOtrzymania: Date | null;
    NIPDostawcy: string;
    NRDokumentu: string;
    KwotaBrutto: number | null;
    Waluta: string;
    StawkaVAT: string;
    MPK: string;
    KontoGL: string;
    Magazyn: boolean | null;
    NrPZ: string;
    Opis: string;
    Zaliczka: string;
    Aprobata1: string;
    Aprobata1Status: boolean | null;
    Aprobata1Godzina: Date | null;
    Aprobata2: string;
    Aprobata2Status: boolean | null;
    Aprobata2Godzina: Date | null;
    Komentarz: string;
    NrAS: string;
    Ksiegowosc: string;
    Zatwierdzenie: boolean | null;
    Kasa: string;
    KasaGodzina: Date | null;
    KsiegowoscGodzina: Date | null;
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `reset(defaultValues)`?